# Wix RNN v3 Navigation.pop() callback?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using Wix's react-native-navigation V3. I'd need to know if there's a way to call a function whenever Navigation.pop() is finished executing.

My specific case scenario is as follows.
I have 3 stack tab buttons, where I can push a new screen and pop back.
All works fine, except for the case that, from that pushed screen, I'd need to go to a different tab. If I mergeOptions directly to change currentTabIndex, the bottomTabs will disappear. Found out that I have to first, pop() and then mergeOptions.

Is there a way to accomplish this? When I run both in the same function, only pop() is triggered, I need to add some sync to this.

This is my current stack structure:

```
const startTabs = () => {
    Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
            bottomTabs: {
                animate: true,
                visible: false,
                drawBehind: true,
                elevation: 8,
                waitForRender: true,
                children: [
                    {
                        stack: {
                            id: 'MainTabStack',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        id: 'MainTab',
                                        name: 'app.MainTab'
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: i18n.t('home'),
                                    icon: iconsMap['home-light'],
                                    selectedIcon: iconsMap['home-solid'],
                                    ...navigatorStyle
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        stack: {
                            id: 'MyProfileTabStack',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        id: 'MyProfileTab',
                                        name: 'app.MyProfileTab'
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: i18n.t('myProfile'),
                                    icon: iconsMap['user-light'],
                                    selectedIcon: iconsMap['user-solid'],
                                    ...navigatorStyle
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        stack: {
                            id: 'MessageTabStack',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        id: 'MessageScreen',
                                        name: 'app.MessageScreen'
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    text: i18n.t('messages'),
                                    icon: iconsMap['message-light'],
                                    selectedIcon: iconsMap['message-solid'],
                                    badgeColor: 'red',
                                    ...navigatorStyle
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So I start from MainTab, then I push a new screen from this MainTab. Let's name it **SingleViewScreen**. When I'm done doing some stuff in SingleViewScreen, by an onPress function I need to pop() this current screen and go directly to MessageScreen.

Any ideas? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [registerCommandCompletedListener](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/events?id=registercommandcompletedlistener)

Invoked when a command (i.e push, pop, showModal etc)  finishes executing in native. If the command contains animations, for example pushed screen animation, the listener is invoked after the animation ends.

Try this

```
// Subscribe
const commandCompletedListener = Navigation.events().registerCommandCompletedListener(({ commandId, completionTime, params }) => {

});
...
// Unsubscribe
commandCompletedListener.remove();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for answering :) Interesting... Is there also a way to filter not only by commandID but also like a "reason" ? because I could either press the go back button to pop it but this specific case scenario is different for the purpose.

Comment: Yes, i implemented this, but it literally enters every time, and it seems that the commandId is the `${commandType}${iteration++}`, on params, i just have a componentId for example. But it seems i don't have any way to filter it by this case scenario.

Comment: I had to do something different, passProps to the pushed screen and execute it after Navigation.pop() to tell the parent to changeTab. It works, although everything happens super fast but still, it works now.

Comment: Im only having a problem with the listener during change of currentTabIndex. It doesn't trigger, only when pressing on tab. Curious if you have any idea on that.